# android background service static field send same msg twice

Tags: android, service, mqtt

I have a big problem that i couldn't find solution. Need your help.

When i try to send just one message in activity using service , it works.
But when i try to send 2 message following another( that means one after other ) , sends the message twice with the same publishTopic2 and pushMsg2.

Code is :

```
PushService.actionPush(getApplicationContext(),publishTopic1,pushMsg1);
PushService.actionPush(getApplicationContext(),publishTopic2,pushMsg2);
```

1- is this from the wrong usage of syncronized keyword ?
2- is it possibe to send two msg after another without

```
public class PushService
        extends Service
{
    // this is the log tag
    public static final String TAG = "DemoPushService";
    public static String IncomingText = "";

    private static String PushMesaj = "";

    // the IP address, where your MQTT broker is running.
    private static final String MQTT_HOST = "";
    // the port at which the broker is running.
    private static int MQTT_BROKER_PORT_NUM = 1883;
    // Let's not use the MQTT persistence.
    private static MqttClientPersistence MQTT_PERSISTENCE = null;
    // We don't need to remember any state between the connections, so we use a
    // clean start.
    private static boolean MQTT_CLEAN_START = true;
    // Let's set the internal keep alive for MQTT to 15 mins. I haven't tested
    // this value much. It could probably be increased.
    private static short MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE = 60 * 15;
    // Set quality of services to 0 (at most once delivery), since we don't want
    // push notifications
    // arrive more than once. However, this means that some messages might get
    // lost (delivery is not guaranteed)
    // private static int[] MQTT_QUALITIES_OF_SERVICE = { 0 } ;
    private static int MQTT_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE = 2;
    // The broker should not retain any messages.
    // private static boolean MQTT_RETAINED_PUBLISH = false;

    // MQTT client ID, which is given the broker. In this example, I also use
    // this for the topic header.
    // You can use this to run push notifications for multiple apps with one
    // MQTT broker.
    public static String MQTT_CLIENT_ID = "begining";
    public static String SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC = "begining";
    private static String PUBLISH_TOPIC = "begining";
    // These are the actions for the service (name are descriptive enough)
    private static final String ACTION_START = MQTT_CLIENT_ID + ".START";
    private static final String ACTION_STOP = MQTT_CLIENT_ID + ".STOP";
    private static final String ACTION_SUBSCRIBE = MQTT_CLIENT_ID
            + ".SUBSCRIBE";
    private static final String ACTION_PUBLISH = MQTT_CLIENT_ID + ".PUBLISH";

    private static final String ACTION_KEEPALIVE = MQTT_CLIENT_ID
            + ".KEEP_ALIVE";
    private static final String ACTION_PUSHMESSAGE = MQTT_CLIENT_ID
            + ".PUSH_MESSAGE";
    private static final String ACTION_PUSHMESSAGE2 = MQTT_CLIENT_ID
            + ".PUSH_MESSAGE";
    private static final String ACTION_RECONNECT = MQTT_CLIENT_ID
            + ".RECONNECT";

    // Connection log for the push service. Good for debugging.
    private ConnectionLog mLog;

    // Connectivity manager to determining, when the phone loses connection
    private ConnectivityManager mConnMan;
    // Notification manager to displaying arrived push notifications
    private NotificationManager mNotifMan;

    // Whether or not the service has been started.
    private boolean mStarted;

    // This the application level keep-alive interval, that is used by the
    // AlarmManager
    // to keep the connection active, even when the device goes to sleep.
    private static final long KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 28;

    // Retry intervals, when the connection is lost.
    private static final long INITIAL_RETRY_INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long MAXIMUM_RETRY_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 30;

    // Preferences instance
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    // We store in the preferences, whether or not the service has been started
    public static final String PREF_STARTED = "isStarted";
    // We also store the deviceID (target)
    public static final String PREF_DEVICE_ID = "deviceID";
    // We store the last retry interval
    public static final String PREF_RETRY = "retryInterval";

    // Notification title
    public static String NOTIF_TITLE = "Hey !!!";
    // Notification id
    private static final int NOTIF_CONNECTED = 0;

    // This is the instance of an MQTT connection.
    private MQTTConnection mConnection;
    private long mStartTime;

    private static clsUser yourInfo;
    public static clsOnlineUsers onlineUsers;
    private static clsUser myInfo;

    // Static method to start the service
    public static void actionStart(Context ctx)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_START);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    public static void actionSubscribe(Context ctx)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_SUBSCRIBE);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    public static void actionPublish(Context ctx)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_PUBLISH);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    // Static method to stop the service
    public static void actionStop(Context ctx)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_STOP);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    // Static method to send a keep alive message
    public static void actionPing(Context ctx)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    public static void actionPush(Context ctx, String publishTopic,
            String pushMsg)
    {
        PUBLISH_TOPIC = publishTopic;
        PushMesaj = pushMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_PUSHMESSAGE);
        ctx.startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        log("Creating service");
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            mLog = new ConnectionLog();
            Log.i(TAG, "Opened log at " + mLog.getPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open log", e);
        }

        // Get instances of preferences, connectivity manager and notification
        // manager
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(TAG, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mConnMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mNotifMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mPrefs.edit().putLong(PREF_RETRY, INITIAL_RETRY_INTERVAL).commit();
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_STARTED, false).commit();

        /*
         * If our process was reaped by the system for any reason we need to
         * restore our state with merely a call to onCreate. We record the last
         * "started" value and restore it here if necessary.
         */
        handleCrashedService();
    }

    // This method does any necessary clean-up need in case the server has been
    // destroyed by the system
    // and then restarted
    private void handleCrashedService()
    {
        if (wasStarted() == true) {
            log("Handling crashed service...");
            // stop the keep alives
            // stopKeepAlives();

            // Do a clean start
            start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        log("Service destroyed (started=" + mStarted + ")");

        // Stop the services, if it has been started
        if (mStarted == true) {
            stop();
        }

        try {
            if (mLog != null)
                mLog.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        log("Service started with intent=" + intent);
        if (intent == null) {
            start();
            return;
        }
        // Do an appropriate action based on the intent.
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_STOP) == true) {
            stop();
            stopSelf();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_START) == true) {
            start();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_KEEPALIVE) == true) {
            keepAlive();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PUBLISH) == true) {
            publish();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SUBSCRIBE) == true) {
            subscribe();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PUSHMESSAGE) == true) {
            sendMessage();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECONNECT) == true) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                reconnectIfNecessary();
            }
        }
    }

    private void subscribe()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            mConnection.subscribeToTopic(SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void publish()
    {

        try {
            // Send a keep alive, if there is a connection.
            if (mStarted == true && mConnection != null) {
                mConnection.sendPushMessage(1);
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            log("MqttException: "
                    + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "NULL"), e);

            mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
            cancelReconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // log helper function
    private void log(String message)
    {
        log(message, null);
    }

    private void log(String message, Throwable e)
    {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, message, e);

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, message);
        }

        if (mLog != null) {
            try {
                mLog.println(message);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    // Reads whether or not the service has been started from the preferences
    private boolean wasStarted()
    {
        return mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_STARTED, false);
    }

    // Sets whether or not the services has been started in the preferences.
    private void setStarted(boolean started)
    {
        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_STARTED, started).commit();
        mStarted = started;
    }

    private synchronized void start()
    {
        log("Starting service...");

        // Do nothing, if the service is already running.
        if (mStarted == true) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Attempt to start connection that is already active");
            return;
        }

        // Establish an MQTT connection
        connect();

        // Register a connectivity listener
        registerReceiver(mConnectivityChanged, new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    }

    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        // Do nothing, if the service is not running.
        if (mStarted == false) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Attempt to stop connection not active.");
            return;
        }

        // Save stopped state in the preferences
        setStarted(false);

        // Remove the connectivity receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityChanged);
        // Any existing reconnect timers should be removed, since we explicitly
        // stopping the service.
        cancelReconnect();

        // Destroy the MQTT connection if there is one
        if (mConnection != null) {
            mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
        }
    }

    private clsUser setUserInfo(String deviceId)
    {
        clsUser u = new clsUser();

        dbUser du = new dbUser(getApplicationContext(), dbUser.DATABASE_NAME,
                null, dbUser.DATABASE_VERSION);

        Cursor c1 = du.Getby(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                null, deviceId, null, null, null);

        u = du.setProperties(c1);
        c1.close();
        du.close();
        return u;

    }

    //
    private synchronized void connect()
    {
        log("Connecting...");

        // Create a new connection only if the device id is not NULL
        if (MQTT_CLIENT_ID == null) {
            log("Device ID not found.");
        } else {
            try {
                MQTT_CLIENT_ID = Config.id(getApplication());
                myInfo = setUserInfo(MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
                mConnection = new MQTTConnection(MQTT_HOST, "user/"
                        + MQTT_CLIENT_ID + "/#");

            } catch (MqttException e) {
                // Schedule a reconnect, if we failed to connect
                log("MqttException: "
                        + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "NULL"));
                if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    scheduleReconnect(mStartTime);
                }
            }
            setStarted(true);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void keepAlive()
    {
        try {
            // Send a keep alive, if there is a connection.
            if (mStarted == true && mConnection != null) {
                mConnection.sendKeepAlive();
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            log("MqttException: "
                    + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "NULL"), e);

            mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
            cancelReconnect();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage()
    {
        try {
            // Send a keep alive, if there is a connection.
            if (mStarted == true && mConnection != null) {
                mConnection.sendPushMessage(); // this does the job
            }
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            log("MqttException: "
                    + (e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "NULL"), e);

            mConnection.disconnect();
            mConnection = null;
            cancelReconnect();
        }
    }

    // Schedule application level keep-alives using the AlarmManager
    private void startKeepAlives()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL,
                KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL, pi);
    }

    // Remove all scheduled keep alives
    private void stopKeepAlives()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_KEEPALIVE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.cancel(pi);
    }

    // We schedule a reconnect based on the starttime of the service
    public void scheduleReconnect(long startTime)
    {
        // the last keep-alive interval
        long interval = mPrefs.getLong(PREF_RETRY, INITIAL_RETRY_INTERVAL);

        // Calculate the elapsed time since the start
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed = now - startTime;

        log(String.valueOf(elapsed));

        // Set an appropriate interval based on the elapsed time since start
        if (elapsed < interval) {
            interval = Math.min(interval * 4, MAXIMUM_RETRY_INTERVAL);
        } else {
            interval = INITIAL_RETRY_INTERVAL;
        }

        log("Rescheduling connection in " + interval + "ms.");

        // Save the new internval
        mPrefs.edit().putLong(PREF_RETRY, interval).commit();

        // Schedule a reconnect using the alarm manager.
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_RECONNECT);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + interval, pi);
    }

    // Remove the scheduled reconnect
    public void cancelReconnect()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, PushService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_RECONNECT);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.cancel(pi);
    }

    private synchronized void reconnectIfNecessary()
    {
        if (mStarted == true && mConnection == null) {
            log("Reconnecting...");
            connect();
        }
    }

    private class MQTTConnection
            implements MqttCallback
    {
        MqttClient mqttClient = null;
        MqttConnectOptions conOpt;
        String myDeviceId;

        // Creates a new connection given the broker address and initial topic
        public MQTTConnection(String brokerHostName, String initTopic)
                throws MqttException
        {
            // Create connection spec

        }

        private void publish(String topicName, int qos, String payload,
                boolean retained) throws MqttException
        {

        }

        /*
         * Sends a message to the message broker, requesting that it be
         * published to the specified topic.
         */
        private void publishToTopic(String topicName, String message)
                throws MqttException
        {

            if ((mqttClient == null) || (mqttClient.isConnected() == false)) {
                // quick sanity check - don't try and publish if we don't have
                // a connection
                log("No connection to public to");
            } else {
                publish(topicName, MQTT_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE, message, false);
            }

        }

        /*
         * Send a request to the message broker to be sent messages published
         * with the specified topic name. Wildcards are allowed.
         */
        private void subscribeToTopic(String topicName1) throws MqttException
        {

            if ((mqttClient == null) || (mqttClient.isConnected() == false)) {
                // quick sanity check - don't try and subscribe if we don't have
                // a connection
                log("Subscribtion failed : Connection error" + "No connection");
            } else {

                mqttClient.subscribe(topicName1, 0);
                Log.v(TAG, "Subscribe To : " + topicName1);

            }
        }

        public void sendPushMessage(int sira) throws MqttException
        {

            publishToTopic(PUBLISH_TOPIC, PushMesaj);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: onStart is deprecated. Use onStartCommand instead.

Comment: @DoctororDrive The comment regarding `onStart()` isn't really relevant to the question, is it? I mean, replacing this with `onStartCommand()` won't solve OP's problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser no, it's just an advice. Deprecated methods aren't guaranteed to be called on all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `actionPush()`, it does the following:

```
    PUBLISH_TOPIC = publishTopic;
    PushMesaj = pushMsg;
```

which saves the arguments in `private static` variables and then calls `startService`. If you do this twice, you will overwrite the `private static` variables with the second set of arguments.

You need to understand that the call to `startService()` is not synchronous. It doesn't start the service immediately and call `onStart()` before the method returns. The service will get started and the call to `onStart()` will occur sometime later (timing isn't under your control here).

You want to put these parameters in the `Intent` that you use to start the service, and retrieve the arguments from the `Intent` in `onStart()`. You can't reliably use `static` variables to do this.

**EDIT: ADD CODE DETAILS**

Change `actionPush()` to this:

```
static final String EXTRA_TOPIC = "EXTRA_TOPIC";
static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";

public static void actionPush(Context ctx, String publishTopic,
        String pushMsg)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, PushService.class);
    i.setAction(ACTION_PUSHMESSAGE);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_TOPIC, publishTopic);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, pushMsg);
    ctx.startService(i);
}
```

and in `onStart()` you can get the arguments out of the `Intent` like this:

```
String topic = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOPIC);
String message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

I'm not going to rewrite the entire program for you. You'll have to figure out now what to do with the arguments. Maybe you can now store them in `private static` variables, but I don't know enough about your program to be able to say if that will work. A better solution would be to pass the arguments through the various methods that you've defined until they get down to the methods where they are used.

Comment: so what should i do ? how to change the code in order to solve my problem ?

Comment: Wow , thank you very much,i tested your advice and it works, so the problem was passing the variables to the intent, I always uses passing parameters to Intents with putExtra ,but in services it did not come to my mind.I thought as classic programming.